# is it possible to retrieve image of contact using Contacts api v3 with the help of universal-image-loader?

Tags: android, gdata-api, universal-image-loader

right now I am retrieving images using following piece of code and it is working perfectly.but I want to implement cache using `universal-image-loader`.I have already implemented it in my other projects in which I was having complete url of image like ~\images\pic1.jpeg .on the other hand,while using Contacts api v3 I have to deal with input streams and I don't have such complete url.so I don't know how to implement `universal-image-loader`.

for the reference:[Contact api v3](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#contact_photo_management)

here is the code which I am using right now:

```
    Bitmap bm=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(HomeActivity.this.getResources(),
            R.drawable.profile_pic);
    CONSTANTS.buffer = new byte[4096];

// iterate the loop upto number of contacts
    for(int i=0;i<CONSTANTS.contactArrayList.size();i++)
    {


//if the contact has any profile pic then retrieve it otherwise set default profile pic from drawable folder

    if(CONSTANTS.contactArrayList.get(i).getContactPhotoLink().getEtag()!=null)
        {
            try
            {
                GDataRequest request = CONSTANTS.mContactService.createLinkQueryRequest(CONSTANTS.contactArrayList.get(i).getContactPhotoLink());
                  request.execute();
                  InputStream in = request.getResponseStream();
                  CONSTANTS.buffer = ByteStreams.toByteArray(in);
                  bm = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(CONSTANTS.buffer, 0, CONSTANTS.buffer.length);
                  in.close();
                  request.end();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                UTILS.Log_e("loadProfilePics error", e.toString());
            }

        }
        else
        {
            bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(HomeActivity.this.getResources(),
                    R.drawable.profile_pic);
        }
         CONSTANTS.contactArrayList.get(i).setContactPhoto(bm);
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `universal-image-loader` allows you to do it. Just follow this steps:

1. You can introduce your own url type, for example `contacts-api-v3://user_id=<user_id>`
2. Provide a way to retrieve `InputStream` for such urls:

   ```
   public class CustomImageDownloader extends URLConnectionImageDownloader {
       @Override
       protected InputStream getStreamFromOtherSource(URI imageUri) throws IOException {
           if (imageUri.getScheme().equals("contacts-api-v3")) {
               // here you can use code provided in your question
               return retriveInputStreamForThisUser();
           }
           return null;
       }
   }
   ```
3. Configure `ImageLoader` to use your `CustomImageDownloader`:

   ```
   final ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder builder = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(context);

   // some basic configuration should be here

   builder.imageDownloader(new CustomImageDownloader());
   ```
4. Now you can use it this way:

   ```
   ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage("contacts-api-v3://user_id=123", imageView);
   ```

Comment: If ContactPhotoLink is something like ```https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/...``` then I recommend replace **https** with **contacts**, pass it to imageLoader: ```imageLoader.displayImage("constacts://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/...")```, then in CustomImageDownloader check ```imageUri.getScheme().equals("contacts")``` and if so replace back **contacts** with **https** and retreive InputStream by this link.